# PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation

Tags: laravel, mariadb

i am using xamp,mysql and laravel 6 and using spatie media library for image uploading and i got stuck at migrating files
my errors are

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for t he right syntax to
>   use near 'json not null, `custom_properties` json not null,
>   `responsive_images` json not n' at line 1")
>
> PDO::prepare("create table `media` (`id` int unsigned not null
>   auto_increment primary key, `model_type` varchar(191) not null,
>   `model_id` char(36) not null, `collection_name` varch ar(191) not
>   null, `name` varchar(191) not null, `file_name` varchar(191) not null,
>   `mime_type` varchar(191) null, `disk` varchar(191) not null, `size`
>   int unsigned not null, `manipulatio ns` json not null,
>   `custom_properties` json not null, `responsive_images` json not null,
>   `order_column` int unsigned null, `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` timestamp null) defau lt character set utf8mb4 collate
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'")

my migration file

```
Schema::create('media', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('model_type');
            $table->uuid('model_id');
            $table->string('collection_name');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('file_name');
            $table->string('mime_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('disk');
            $table->unsignedInteger('size');
            $table->json('manipulations');
            $table->json('custom_properties');
            $table->json('responsive_images');
            $table->unsignedInteger('order_column')->nullable();
            $table->nullableTimestamps();
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)

Comment: From the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/): "The JSON alias was added in MariaDB 10.2.7.". So your version of MariaDB is too old.

Comment: thanks for your utmost valuable reply